# Ruby on Rails - £ sign troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I have `<%= f.label :cost, "Cost (£/m)" %>` in a form. When the form is rendered the "£" sign comes out as �. I am using utf-8 encoding.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you specifying an incompatible encoding in the HTML? What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion from my experience) :

1. verify that your file erb is saved in utf-8
2. I recomend you to use [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) method

Comment: How do I verify if the erb is being saved in utf-8. I am not outputting a number just the £ symbol.

Comment: When you save the file in your text editor, check the UTF-8 encoding is selected. Many Windows text editors will save under the non-UTF-8 ‘system code page’ (also—misleadingly—known as ANSI) by default, which is unfortunate.

Comment: A set of editors has got View->Show current encoding functionality, for example, personally, I like PSPad.

Comment: Using Dreamweaver as editor, I have escaped to &pound; in other erb with success, but this form partial just doesn't work.

Comment: @freshest,     what form partial you mentioned?

Comment: My code `<%= f.label :cost, "Cost (£/m)" %>` is in a form which is in a Ruby on Rails partial _form.html.erb which is used in views new.html.erb and edit.html.erb.

Comment: You can use a Ruby string literal escape. What that looks like depends on what encoding you're serving the page as. In ISO-8859-1, `"Cost (\xA3/m)"`. In UTF-8, `"Cost (\xC2\xA3/m)"`. Really though you should be serving your pages, and saving your files, as UTF-8, in which case you should just be able to use `£` directly. [Dreamweaver settings.](http://superuser.com/questions/46693/dreamweaver-reverts-to-western-encoding-after-its-been-changed-to-utf8/48723#48723)

Comment: @bobince - After some more investigation I have discovered that all the files RoR generates when creating a new application seem to be saved with Western(ISO-8859-1) encoding (I am developing on a Windows machine). And so I am having this confict with the £ character.  Should RoR be generating the framework files in this way?  If not how can I set it to generate the files with UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Are you outputting HTML? If so you need to escape the character `<%= f.label :cost, "Cost (&pound;/m)" %>`

Comment: I am using `<meta charset = "UTF-8" />` and I am outputing HTML.  I have also tried escaping to &pound; , when I do this I just get &pound;.  The form is created in a partial, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Either send your page with UFT-8 encoding, or send the pound sign as `&pound;` (or `&#163;` if you're sending XML rather than HTML).

Comment: @freshest - really? I assume you're seeing the encoded string as per your comment on the other answer? In that case, I'd say your problem is that the label function is trying to do its own encoding for you. How you solve that, I don't know. Sorry.